# How can I create a custom function for validation rules in yii?

Tags: php, yii, validation

I have created a form with some entities (say name,address,etc.). And I have defined validation rules in model class. Client side validation is working perfectly as desired. Now I need to create custom validation rules. For that,in reference with http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/#hh0 ,  I have created a method called valid_number() in my model, and defined a simple null checking (I know there are built in rules for validating null,email,password, etc.. Here I have demonstrated a simple method of validation, actually I'm planning to do some custom validations). Please refer the code below. And please let me know what I am doing wrong.

//model

```
class Employee extends CActiveRecord{
  public $number;
  public function rules(){
     return array(
                  array('number','valid_number'),
                  );
  }


 public function valid_number($attribute,$params){
    if($this->$attribute == '' ){
         CModel::addError($attribute, 'Number is null');
    }
   }
```

//view

```
</fieldset>
   <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model, 'number'); ?>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: What is the error? the model is validated whitout any error, a php error happened?

Comment: So what exactly happens? Is your method called? What does `var_dump($this->$attribute)` output?

Answer (score 3):

`CModel::addError` should be `$this->addError`.

Comment: 'Didn't work' doesn't **work**, whats the output? whats the error? what info do you have from a debug attempt?

Comment: @Pradeep You should call CFormModel::error function to display number attribute errors. like this: `<?php echo $form->error($model, 'number'); ?>` and if just validate attribute is empty, you maybe can try  `required` validator

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$this->addError($attribute, 'Your error message');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling the static function `CModel::addError`?

You could just call `addError` of the object and it works:

```
public function valid_number($attribute, $params) {
    if ($this->$attribute == '' ) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Number is null');
    }
}
```